# how to implement many to many relationship models with back and forward Reference which one model have two fields in another?

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I have two models named Exercise and Muscle, which have a many-to-many relationship.
Muscle have two variant

- HelperMuscle
- TargetMuscle

that referred from Muscle in Exercise

```golang
type Exercise struct {
    ID   uint    `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    HelperMuscles   []Muscle     `json:"helper_muscles" gorm:"many2many: exercis_helper_muscles"`
    TargetMuscles   []Muscle     `json:"target_muscles" gorm:"many2many: exercis_target_muscles"`
}

type Muscle struct {
    ID          uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Exercises   []Exercise     `json:"exercises" gorm:"many2many: ?"`
}
```

My question is what should I put as the **pivot table name** in the muscle model?

Answer (score 1):

GORM doesn't support having one slice for two different relationships in the way you described.
You could also do direct SQL queries to fetch the associated exercises.